# How can i create webapps-javaee directory in external linux tomcat 10

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, java-ee-6, tomcat10

I have javaEE webapp which initialize in external tomcat. After upgrading to tomcat 10, it is not initialized. In default configuration, there is no webapps-javaee directory in external tomcat 10.

I created webapps-javaee manually with mkdir but it does not work. How can i configure this feature for my JAVA EE application ?

Comment: Tomcat 9 & 10 are not compatible JEE version wise. Refer: https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html 9.x / 10.x section. Check if your JEE application is compiled for JEE9